# How to access data bound objects in listView using DataSource property?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, checkedlistbox

So I have this radclv_peças which is a `radCheckedListBox` control populated with `Peça` custom objects and I'm trying to get the object currently selected using the `SelectedItem` property. The problem is I don´t know how to access these objects which I bound using the `DataSource` property like this:

```
radclv_peças.DataSource = Program.M_Wardrobe.ListaPeças;
radclv_peças.DisplayMember = "Name";
radclv_peças.ValueMember = "Id";
```

I need to change the image in a `pictureBox` according to the `Peça` currently selected in the `listView`. The idea is to get the currently selected item by ID and compare it with all `Peça` objects contained in `Program.M_Wardrobe.ListaPeças`(MVC pattern) which is of type `List<Peça>`, until I find the one with the same ID and send it to the pictureBox.
So, how can I access the Id, or other properties, of the items bound in the radCheckedListBox (Telerik) with the DataSource property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik's `RadCheckedListBox.SelectedItem` has a `DataBoundItem` property. This represents a specific object that the `SelectedItem` is bound to out of the list of objects that the `RadCheckedListBox` is bound to. By casting this at runtime to your object type, you can access its properties in your event handler.

```
private void RadCheckedListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = radCheckedListBox.SelectedItem?.DataBoundItem as Peça;
}
```

Once you have the item, you are free to use it how you want from there.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165013/discussion-on-answer-by-scott-baldric-how-to-access-data-bound-objects-in-listvi).